# Linear dependence of gradient vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

I was wondering how you find the points (x,y) where ∇g1(x,y) and ∇g2(x,y) are linearly dependent.

The two functions I have are:
g1(x,y)= xy and g2= y-x^2

I've found the gradient vectors ∇g1= (y,x) and ∇g2= (-2x,1)

Now I'm wondering how to find the points where they are linearly dependent?

Thanks,

Comment: Arrange your vectors into a matrix, find when the determinant is zero. $y + 2x^2 = 0$

Comment: A pair of vectors is linearly dependent if they are scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! If you 
have a minute, since this is your first post, please take a look
at [how to format mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE if you need to do so. 
Furthermore, I suggest that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
as a quick reference for future posts. Cheers!